# Cannot connect to SQL Server 2012

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to connect to a SQL Server 2012 database using C#, both the server and program are on the same computer. When I try to connect I get an exception:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)

There is an inner exception simply saying {"The parameter is incorrect"}.

I'm trying to connect using this

```
SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection("Server=(local)\\MSSQLSERVER;Database=Test;User ID=logger;Password=logger;Trusted_Connection=False");
sql.Open();
```

I have a SQL login called logger with the same text as the password and it is mapped the database Test. I believe I have the server set up to take remote logins.

Any ideas as to what I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection("Server=.;Database=Test;User ID=logger;Password=logger;Trusted_Connection=False");
```

Or

```
SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection("Server=local;Database=Test;User ID=logger;Password=logger;Trusted_Connection=False");
```

Comment: The first one seems to have worked, got me as to why. Thanks. Now I just need to figure out why my queries do not return data.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be `(localdb)` rather than `(local)`

[connectionstrings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)

The error message does state (at the end):

> Connection string is not valid

so you need to check it at the linked page.